# Problem in including a youtube video using media9

Tags: media9

I am trying to include a youtube video in my document. However, the video is not playable in the created PDF in Acrobat in Windows 7. Interestingly, the example in the `media9` manual is played with no problem and I am using the same settings for another youtube video. The following is a MWE, where the first media is not playable (which is the one I want to include in my document) and the second one is the one which I found in the manual. Could someone shed light on this?

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{media9}

\begin{document}

The following youtube video is the one I want to include in the document.
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includemedia[
    width=0.6\linewidth,height=0.3375\linewidth,
    activate=pageopen,
    flashvars={
        modestbranding=1 % no YT logo in control bar
        &autohide=1 % controlbar autohide
        &showinfo=0 % no title and other info before start
        &rel=0 % no related videos after end
    }
        ]{}{http://youtu.be/wKFRGVzrWgQ}
\end{figure}

The following youtube video is adapted from media9 package manual.
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includemedia[
    width=0.6\linewidth,height=0.3375\linewidth,
    activate=pageopen,
    flashvars={
        modestbranding=1 % no YT logo in control bar
        &autohide=1 % controlbar autohide
        &showinfo=0 % no title and other info before start
        &rel=0 % no related videos after end
        }
        ]{}{http://www.youtube.com/v/w3f-WyDqOUw?rel=0}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution. The problem with the first youtube video is that I provided the `short link` to `\includemedia`. The URL in the `media9` package seems to be the `Long Link`. So, in the MWE that I provided in the question, what is important in the first youtube url is the 11 character-case-sensitive `VIDEO_ID#`. Therefore, in the first youtube link, I have:

```
http://youtu.be/wKFRGVzrWgQ
```

which must be simply replaced by:

```
http://www.youtube.com/v/wKFRGVzrWgQ
```

So the complete working example is as follows:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{media9}

\begin{document}

The following youtube video is the one I want to include in the document.
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includemedia[
    width=0.6\linewidth,height=0.3375\linewidth,
    activate=pageopen,
    flashvars={
        modestbranding=1 % no YT logo in control bar
        &autohide=1 % controlbar autohide
        &showinfo=0 % no title and other info before start
        &rel=0 % no related videos after end
    }
        ]{}{http://www.youtube.com/v/wKFRGVzrWgQ}
\end{figure}

The following youtube video is adapted from media9 package manual.

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includemedia[
    width=0.6\linewidth,height=0.3375\linewidth,
    activate=pageopen,
    flashvars={
        modestbranding=1 % no YT logo in control bar
        &autohide=1 % controlbar autohide
        &showinfo=0 % no title and other info before start
        &rel=0 % no related videos after end
        }
        ]{}{http://www.youtube.com/v/w3f-WyDqOUw}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Now both youtube videos are playable with no problem.