# problem including a youtube video in a pdf via latex

Tags: beamer, media9

I am trying to embed a YouTube video onto a pdf using LaTeX.  Here is is the command that I use:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usepackage{media9}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \includemedia[
        width=0.6\linewidth,height=0.3375\linewidth,
        activate=pageopen,
        flashvars={
            modestbranding=1 % no YT logo in control bar
            &autohide=1 % controlbar autohide
            &showinfo=0 % no title and other info before start
            &rel=0 % no related videos after end
            }
            ]{}{http://www.youtube.com/v/w3f-WyDqOUw}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Can you please help me?

but the video does not run.  Does anyone have an insight?

Comment: See for example http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/174954/problem-in-including-a-youtube-video-using-media9 or http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14751/is-it-possible-to-embed-a-youtube-video-using-latex

Comment: I did the exact thing from those posts but it still does not work

Comment: And can you tell us which pdf viewer you have tried? `media9` only works on a small subset, such as acrobat.

Comment: adobe acrobat reader DC

Comment: I tried with acrobat reader XI and TeXlive2016 and your example works. So I am out of ideas. Maybe interesting for others, which version of Mactex do you use?

Comment: I don't see a java script but I see java control panel.  It says java in the browser in enabled.

Comment: I now see what you mean.  Yes, it is enabled.

Comment: Wow. AR DC asked me to allow access to 6 sites in order to view this video. Maybe they are disabled on your system (Preferences>Trust Manager).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because not a latex problem, but of the pdf viewer